# dividir um arquivo HTML

Tags: html

Eu to querendo fazer algo, mas não to sabendo como. Olhem o código abaixo (em `html`) ao clicar no botão "H" é aberto um campo de texto logo abaixo dele. Até aí tudo bem, mas o que eu desejaria era que esse campo de texto, que acabou abrindo quando eu cliquei no "H", ficasse escrito em outro arquivo `html`, não tudo no mesmo arquivo. Como se dividisse esse arquivo `html` em outros dois arquivos, mas eu não sei como fazer isso mantendo esse mesmo efeito.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    .description{display:none;border-radius:10px;}
    .description:target{display:block;}
    .descriptions{margin:1.5em;}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="#002_he">H</a>

        <div class="description g-nobre" id="002_he">
            <h2><a href="elemento/002_he">Hélio</a></h2>
            <p>queria que os comandos que ficassem nessa parte, fossem escritos em um arquivo diferente do arquivo que tem o botão.</p>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Voce pode criar um include, se é exatamente o que entendi. Entao voce cria outro arquivo html, podendo ser na mesma raiz do principal. e chama-lo como uma tag html comum. Segue um link que pode ajudar:http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: Dividir o arquivo html? Isso soa meio estranho, mas o "H" é um link, ele pode apontar para outro arquivo html (entenda outra página) e lá abrir o campo de texto, só mudar o link pra outra página. Você pode também passar um parâmetro para a página via querystring, para só exibir o campo caso você passe esse parâmetro.

Answer (score -1):

Exemplo:
**index.html**

```html
    <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    .description{display:none;border-radius:10px;}
    .description:target{display:block;}
    .descriptions{margin:1.5em;}
    </style>

    <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href="#002_he">H</a>

    <div class="description g-nobre" id="002_he">
        <h2><a href="elemento/002_he">Hélio</a></h2>
            <div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
       w3.includeHTML();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**content.html**

```html
 
<h1>Códigos restantes...</h1>
<p>Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Nec orci ornare consequat. Praesent lacinia ultrices consectetur. Sed non ipsum felis. Detraxit consequat et quo num tendi nada. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio. Não sou faixa preta cumpadi, sou preto inteiris, inteiris. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Delegadis gente finis, bibendum egestas augue arcu ut est. Leite de capivaris, leite de mula manquis sem cabeça.</p>
<a href="https://wigny.github.io">Link</a>
```